# How to make Linear Search search from left to right in Python?

Tags: python

Is there a way to make a linear search, where it searches from left to right of the list until they converge and find the key being searched?

```
def linear_search(alist,key):
    for i in range(len(alist)):
        if alist[i] == key:
            return i
    return -1



alist = input('Enter the list of numbers: ')
alist = alist.split()
alist = [int(x) for x in alist]

while True:
    key = int(input("The number to search for: "))

    index = linear_search(alist, key)

    if index >= 0:
        print(f"{key} was found at index {index}.")
    else:
        print(f'{key} was not found.')
```

Comment: So what's the problem with the code you've posted? It looks to me like it should work fine, and does exactly what you ask in the question.

Comment: Are you asking, is their a built-in function for linear search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change range function to return the indices from right to left by using this:

```
for i in range(len(alist)-1,-1,-1):
    # your logic
```

Comment: @Studyante please minus one from len of list. Check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use in-built module as well to track the index of the item in list. Here it goes:

```
for index, value in enumerate(mylist):
    # <logic>
```